# Drawing rings in QGIS

Tags: qgis, digitizing, circle

I plan to use for positioning and tracking of areas worked for underwater mining.

I am trying to draw rings using Rectangles Ovals Digitizing plugin.

But there is very little info available.

Comment: do you have a centre and radius?

Answer (score 3):

Consider also using ["Geometry Generator"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html?#the-geometry-generator) which contains functions [`make_circle()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#make-circle) and [`difference()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#difference).

Pasting this expression `difference(make_circle($geometry, 100), make_circle($geometry, 50))` will lead to achieving the desired result, see image below.

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

You have the tools to create buffers in QGIS, create the first, then the second one from one center and different sizes, and then cut the smaller one...

Answer (score 1):

Possible by means of the ["Multi-ring buffer (constant distance)"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multi-ring-buffer-constant-distance) geoalgorithm from the QGIS's Toolbox.

[image: example]

Afterwards, choose the required rings, others can be easily deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the solution with ["Geometry Generator"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html?#the-geometry-generator) which intended to provide a visual solution, nevertheless, it is possible to achieve rings as completely new polygon layer using ["Geometry by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) geoalgorithm from the QGIS's Toolbox.

Pasting this expression `difference(make_circle($geometry, 100), make_circle($geometry, 50))` into *'Geometry expression'* will lead to achieving the desired result, see image below.

[image: result]